# "Ampersand not allowed" in Azure DevOps Release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Forgive me because this one is difficult to reproduce.

We are using Azure DevOps to release to a machine on premise. We are using Microsoft's JobHelper.ps1 and SessionHelper.ps1 from here: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/Common/RemoteDeployer and we have not modified them.

JobHelper Get-JobResults is called, and ultimately calls SessionHelper Retry-Connection over and over again with the message "Ampersand not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; use '&' to pass ampersand as a string."

We do not have any ampersands in usernames or passwords or machine names. The only ampersands in either of these files are on lines 173 and 176. There are no ampersands in the file that calls JobHelper.ps1. We have other releases that go through this same flow with no problem.

Has anyone experienced this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed this by updating the machine we were releasing to to the latest PowerShell version.